# Tailwind CSS hidden and visible

Tags: css, frontend, tailwind-css, styling, hidden

Backend dev here learning front. I am trying to hide an element on small and medium screens and visible on the rest of the screens.

But the thing is when I do `sm:hidden` it hides the element for small screens and above. And when I try to do `sm:hidden md:visible` the element is not visible on medium screens and above. How should I go about this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As we can read in official [docs](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/responsive-design) :

> By default, Tailwind uses a mobile-first breakpoint system

Then In Your case on small breakpoint `hidden` and `visible` on **Large** `lg` breakpoints and above :

```
<div class="hidden lg:block">
  <!-- ... -->
</div>
```

---

Example:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="hidden lg:block">
    <h1 class="text-3xl font-bold underline">
      Hello world!
    </h1>
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

[image]

Comment: It worked. thank you dude. I cant upvote tho because I just made the account

Comment: @carl But you can accept answer as it solved your problem :-P !  You're Welcome! ;-)

Comment: Since Tailwind v3.2 it can be shorten as `max-lg:hidden` in that case